# VB script and COM

Tags: com, asp-classic, vbscript

I want to call certain functions of a COM component from ASP. I would like to know

```
How can I create a COM object?. 
How can I use VARIANTS to pass to the COM object? 
Can I pass reference parameters from ASP to COM object? 
What are the limitations of passing reference objects to COM?
```

Where would I get more information about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a COM object?.

Use the [CreateObject function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_createobject.asp)

```
Set Obj = CreateObject("COMProgID")
```

> How can I use VARIANTS to pass to the COM object?

[VBScript has only one data type called a Variant.](http://www.csidata.com/custserv/onlinehelp/vbsdocs/vbs6.htm)

> Can I pass reference parameters from ASP to COM object?

Yes.

> What are the limitations of passing reference objects to COM?

I got lost with this one...

Comment: Is it possible to get a com-object another way? I am trying to connect to the same application that i already instantiated elsewhere.

Comment: @tarrasch If the automation server is implemented properly, you should not have any problems using createobject to connect a new client to it.